# Running Windows CE / Windows Mobile applications on the Pi

Tags: windows

Is it possible for .NET Compact Framework applications compiled to Windows CE / Windows Mobile to be execute on the Raspberry Pi with the help of Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is purely a .Net application, then you may want take a look at the [Mono-Project](http://www.mono-project.com/). From there:

> Mono is an open source implementation of Microsoft's .NET Framework based on the ECMA standards for C# and the Common Language Runtime

Since the Compact Framework is a subset of the full framework there is a good chance that your program may not use any api's that were not implemented in Mono.

Comment: Hum, I forgot about Mono. I'll check if the applications are pure .Net and if they work on my Pi. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: I got a Command Line app to run fine. But I get an error when I try to run a Forms app. Running Forms apps on the framebuffer would be excellent.